# How to create variables inside tf.function decorated method?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Cannot create a `tf.Variable` (while I should) in a `tf.function` decorated method:

```
@tf.function
def some_func():
    x = tf.Variable([1, 2, 3])
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:262 __call__  **
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:244 _variable_v2_call
    return previous_getter(
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
    return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:716 invalid_creator_scope
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

I think there is some workaround using:

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

but I also think that it affects performance, which the whole point of `tf.function` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, you can create variables inside a @tf.function decorated method, as long as your variable is created only once.
Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class YourClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = True

    @tf.function
    def your_function(self):

        if self.first == True:
            self.first = False
            self.your_variable = tf.Variable([0]) 

c = YourClass()
c.your_function()
```

******** UPDATED ************

Since you mentioned you just want to update, not actually create, you could use tf.assign

Code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class YourClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.your_variable = tf.Variable([0])

    @tf.function
    def your_function(self):

        tf.compat.v1.assign(self.your_variable,value=[1]) 

c = YourClass()
c.your_function()
```

Comment: No, I need to be able to call the decorated function any number of times and at each time the variable will hold a different value

Comment: @bullseye, you can use tf.assign. I have updated the code in the answer